# Change thumbnail size for Media Library

Tags: media-library, thumbnails

I can't seem to find a way to change the size of the images in the Media Library. For some reason the full picture is being loaded in the media library, and this makes it really slow. I've tried:

Changing the post-thumbnail, medium and medium_large values with `add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail', 180, 180, true );`
Tried hooking in on `shortcode_atts_gallery` with no effect when changing the `$output['size']` value

Is there any way I can make Wordpress fetch the cropped versions of these pictures rather than displaying the full image?

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting question as I knew nothing about modifying the default behaviour of the Media Library. So, I ended up doing some research on the matter.

I found out that the Media Library uses [`wp_ajax_query_attachments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_query_attachments/) to get the images and other media. Inside the ajax function there's [`ajax_query_attachments_args`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/ajax_query_attachments_args) that can be used to modify the arguments for the attachment `WP_Query`.

After the `WP_Query` the ajax function uses [`wp_prepare_attachment_for_js`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js/) (function and filter) on the queried posts before they are sent back with `wp_send_json_success()`.

Perhaps you could try playing around with `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` filter and see, if you can achieve the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This might get me a solution.